# How can I make a stepper motor run until I press a specific keypad button on Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, keypad

Here is my code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Stepper.h>
#include <Key.h>
#include <Keypad.h>

const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;
const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 1; //one column
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'-'},
  {'+'},
  {'I'},
  {'0'}};
 byte rowPins[ROWS] = {6,7,8,9};
 byte colPins[COLS] = {10};

int count = 0;
LiquidCrystal lcd(A5,A4,A3,A2,A1,A0);
Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 2,4,3,5);
Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);
int plannedSpeed = 50;

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  Stepper.setSpeed(plannedSpeed);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  char key = keypad.getKey();
  Serial.println(plannedSpeed);
  if (key == '-') {
    plannedSpeed = plannedSpeed - 1;
    Serial.println(plannedSpeed);
    delay(10);
  }
  if (key == '+') {
    plannedSpeed = plannedSpeed +1;
    Serial.println(plannedSpeed);
    delay(10);
      }
  if (key == 'I') {
    myStepper.step(stepsPerRevolution);
    Serial.print("Running at " );
    Serial.println(plannedSpeed);
    delay(10);
  }
}
```

I'm trying to code it so that I can choose the speed with the keypad, and the motor starts when I press the 'I' button, and stops when I press the 'O' button. How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected your code and commented where necessary. You had some small problems I fixed as well:

1. You were decrementing `plannedSpeed` without stopping it from dropping below the minimum value, i.e. `0`.
2. You were incrementing `plannedSpeed` without stopping it from going above the maximum value, i.e. `stepsPerRevolution`.
3. You weren't changing the value of `plannedSpeed` when starting the stepper motor.

```cpp
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Stepper.h>
#include <Key.h>
#include <Keypad.h>

const int stepsPerRevolution = 200;
const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 1; //one column
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'-'},
  {'+'},
  {'I'},
  {'0'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {6, 7, 8, 9};
byte colPins[COLS] = {10};

int count = 0;
LiquidCrystal lcd(A5, A4, A3, A2, A1, A0);
Stepper myStepper(stepsPerRevolution, 2, 4, 3, 5);
Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);

int plannedSpeed = 50;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  Stepper.setSpeed(plannedSpeed);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  char key = keypad.getKey();
  Serial.println(plannedSpeed);
  if (key == '-') {
    if (--plannedSpeed < 0) // Decrease plannedSpeed 
      plannedSpeed = 0; // Make sure it does not go below 0
    Serial.println(plannedSpeed);
    delay(10);
  }
  else if (key == '+') {
    if (++plannedSpeed > stepsPerRevolution) // Increase plannedSpeed 
      plannedSpeed = stepsPerRevolution; // Make sure it does not go above stepsPerRevolution
    Serial.println(plannedSpeed);
    delay(10);
  }
  else if (key == 'I') {
    plannedSpeed = stepsPerRevolution; // Set plannedSpeed to maximum
    myStepper.step(plannedSpeed); // Set stepper to plannedSpeed
    Serial.print("Running at " );
    Serial.println(plannedSpeed);
    delay(10);
  }
  else if (key == '0') {
    plannedSpeed = 0; // Set plannedSpeed to 0
    myStepper.step(plannedSpeed); // Set stepper to plannedSpeed
    Serial.print("Stopping at " );
    Serial.println(plannedSpeed);
    delay(10);
  }
}
```